# index.php in URL

Tags: permalinks

Trying to remove "/index.php/" from URL,

The .htaccess file location is

```
./var/www/html/.htaccess
```

and the content

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule (.*) /index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

however it doesn't work, accessing a web page is possible only with "/index.php/".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to Settings >Permalink Settings.

Check **Post name**

Click on **Save Change** button.

[image]

And this should be the [default htaccess](https://wordpress.org/support/article/htaccess/). WordPress can manage it's own htaccess so no need to manually add htaccess rules. I would delete your htaccess file and then save permalink settings.

```
# BEGIN WordPress

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

# END WordPress
```

Comment: Unable to edit .htaccess file: "If your .htaccess file was writable, we could do this automatically, but it isn’t so these are the mod_rewrite rules you should have in your .htaccess file. Click in the field and press CTRL + a to select all."

Comment: The easiest solution is to delete your htaccess and save permalink settings so that WP can generate htaccess on its own. Seems like your WordPress root folder has a permission issue. It depends on the hosting you are using which is a completely different topic. Try this link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34026663/how-to-make-htaccess-writeable-for-wordpress

Comment: You can always edit your htaccess file manually and add the rule I have given above.

Comment: When searching ".htaccess" it shows a list, not sure what file is the right one.

Comment: What type of hosting are you using? if you are using shared hosting, it should be at the document root. For example, public_html. It is in where the wp-config.php file, wp-content, wp-includes etc folders are located.

Comment: You have already stated that it is in this location. `./var/www/html/.htaccess`

Comment: It is correct, but it is the file that I created. I am hosting the server.

Comment: Just replace your htaccess with the one provided above. and then go to permalink settings and save change.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work, when trying to access a page without "index.php" it shows: "Not Found
The requested URL was not found on this server."

Comment: Try it with a different browser/clean your browser cache.

Comment: Same on Chrome/Edge/Explorer with history deleted. It looks like server side issue in my opinion.

Comment: In my opinion the .htaccess file is not being read. When adding a line "deny from all" no error is shown.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is solved by changing the following line inside "httpd.conf" file:

```
AllowOverride None
```

to

```
AllowOverride All
```